# ListView with horizontally scrollable views

Tags: java, android

I'm currently developing an app in android.
I have a really basic listview that has 3 elements in his adapter:
1 imageview and 2 textviews.
These 3 items are inside a constraint layout.

All i ask is if i can make this layout (imgview + 2 tview) scrollable horizontally.

I've tried adding the layout to a horizontalscrollview, it works but i can't take the list onclicklistener.

Comment: If you have only 3 views, then why do you need a ListView ? Just use the HorizontalScrollView as you did, and **setOnClickListener()** on each of them.

Comment: @Sumit Anantwar I assume he means 3 per list item, since he says 3 elements in the adapter.

Comment: @BobanTalevski, you probably have a point here.

Comment: @Mark Walter, please post the code for your adapter, and the layout xml for the ListView Item

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to be able to click on a list item? You could try adding a click listener to the scrollView. You probably also need to set clickable = true on the scrollview (not sure which is the default) and also just in case set clickable = false to all 3 child elements so they don't "eat" the click instead of the scrollView.

Answer (score 0):

Use RecyclerView instead, you can add the onClickListener inside the adapter itself, or if you want the clickListener to be more interactive between your adapter and your activity/fragment, you can try using interface inside the adapter.